# Would this be a viable character concept for Deadlands Classic

Tags: character-creation, deadlands-classic

I would have a martial artist take the Huckster Arcane Background instead of Enlightened (or I could have both and ignore the Chi Edge). The idea is that this character had discovered the Hunting Grounds and learning from Hucksters about how they mentally control the Manitou to use thieir powers/learn their secrets, she decides that this is could be an interesting path to enlightenment so trains in a unique form of mental battle to shape the Manito's power; she decides to use the art of Tummo to help focus the Manitous power. In the process of developing her Hex she first learns the Flicker and Flare Tricks; these two Tricks combined with her technique of controlling her body's internal temperature allows her to combine the Hell's Fury Hex, with the Cold Snap Hex, creating what she dub's "Hell's Cold Fury" or "Punishment of The Icy Mountain"(based on one of the levels of China's version of hell).

This combination also allows her the ability to essentially perform the opposite effect of the normal Cold Snap Hex at her discretion, allowing her to increase the Corporal Traits of herself or others. Off course to pull these tricks off she also had to learn the Corporal Tweak/Twist Hexes as well.

The end result is that she can cloak herself in a fiery aura or freezing aura, and use the former to engulf her opponents in flames, or the latter to form ice on their bodies, wounding them via frostburn. She can also use these to respectively increase or decrease the physical stats of a target (using the former on herself and allies naturally). She also knows how to use the Flicker Trick to decrease the brightness of the aura formed allowing her some more subtly, and the Flare Trick to increase the damage or use her aura to create a light. In fact the Flare trick is necessary for her to actually use Hell's Fury offensively since it's normally a defensive technique (meaning the only people getting burned normally are those attacking the caster).

The biggest downside here is that due to her focusing techniques and basing these abilities around manipulation of the the Hell's Fury Hex, the range of all of these are limited to Self/Touch. She can't dim or increase artificial lights from a distance-let alone at all. She is only limited to the aura and anything that comes into contact with it.

Making lemonade here, she learns how to combine these with her martial arts training to use her powers by striking at a target's pressure points to manipulate the internal chi flow. With strikes against an opponent she numbs her opponent's limbs, or she can touch an ally's pressure points to improve their Corporeal Traits.

With this she has also combined the Bandage and Preserve Tricks, allowing her to use the heat of her aura to sterilize and cauterize wounds, the idea being that she learns and alters Preserve to help prevent infection like the Trick normally prevents Food from rotting. Off course she can't use this Trick now the normal way by combining it with Bandage and the technique as a whole tends to hurt like hell. Likewise it is only useful for minor wounds. Still with this and her version of Corporal Tweak, she can heal those minor wounds.

TL;DR: A martial artist decides to learn the ways of the Huckster instead of the Enlightened to manipulate the Chi of herself and others, developing a functional Chi Aura in the process. It is a long and arduous process off course. This was helped somewhat by the fact she had an ally and close lover who worked with her to develop this Chi Hex. Sadly this ally lost her life after going bust to a Manitou after the two put the final touches on the Hex...while my character was successful, her lover was burned through the inside out...and became Harrowed. The new undead corpse thanked her for the development of this new power and escaped with the Chi Huckster vowing to put her lover's body and soul to rest, and stop the perversion of their art.

A big issue however is that a Shan Fran temple where she trained found out about her "cavorting with demons" and branded her a heretic thanks to the damage the Harrowed caused on the way out. So basically she has monks after her head and a bounty on top of that too...and it doesn't help that using her aura means that despite her best efforts, she got a minor Obvious Hinderance effect on her when she uses her abilities (people can see a faint glow/mist around her)

Your thoughts?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? As the question currently reads it seems better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) but there are many questions that we could answer if you articulate them for us :) (Defining what you consider [viable](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11532/44723) would be a great starting point)

Comment: We could then for example evaluate whether the concept does what you want it to do as defined by your eligibility criteria - does it meet your concept, does it suit your game, but since we don't know how your table works, we can't really answer this until you define these criteria for us.